# Elasticsearch Rails Bulk indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch, sidekiq

I have around 1.5M data in postgres database that I need to reindex. I used ActiveRecord's find_each method in one sidekiq worker to pass those objects to another worker that does reindexing for each object.

```
worker1

# Perform in batch of 200 in 2 minutes.
type.find_each(batch_size: 200) do |object|
    Elasticsearch::Worker2.perform_in(2.minutes, :index, type, object.id, "new_index_name")
end
```

worker2

```
def index_object(object, index_name)
  object.__elasticsearch__.index_document(index: index_name)
end
```

But I ran into the following issue:

```
[429] {"code":429,"message":"Concurrent request limit exceeded. Please consider batching your requests, or contact support@bonsai.io for help."}
```

Anyone have idea how to do batch requests using elasticsearch rails?

Answer (score 1):

According to Bonsai FAQ they:

> We limit the number of concurrent requests. In practice, the actual requests per second this allows is based on the speed of the requests you are executing. Request limits vary at different plan levels. We are still making changes and measuring real-world limits to determine sensible plan defaults. Rate-limited requests will fail with a HTTP 429 error indicating that you contact us so that we can work with you to accommodate your usage. [bonsai FAQ](https://bonsai.io/faq)

So you can either increase your usage (paying I would guess) or you can batch your requests below their limit of 1 update per second, ElasticSearch directly provides you with a [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) which would be a good alternative for you, as you are already using elasticsearch-rails gem you can take advantage of the integration, this article has a good example I have used to index records with elastic-rails in the past [bulk_index](https://timsjpark.wordpress.com/2016/07/13/indexing-with-the-elasticsearch-bulk-api/)